# return table as function value

Tags: sqlanywhere

I'm trying to return table as function value.
My code, but gives syntax error:

```
drop function if EXISTS fn_must_edukas;
CREATE FUNCTION fn_must_edukas()
returns Table as
return(
Select Top 1 v_mangijad.isik_nimi as mängijaNimi,(SUM(punkt)) as punktid_mustad from v_punkti join 
v_mangijad on v_mangijad.isik_id=v_punkti.mangija
where varv='M'
GROUP BY mängijaNimi
order by punktid_mustad desc);
select fn_must_edukas()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Einsener36. Please note that SQL is a catch-all term for languages that query relational databases. Each relational database system implements a dialect of SQL. Each dialect is sufficiently different that SQL for one database system will not work for another. When asking questions about SQL, always add a tag for your particular database system. E.g. one of Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have one problem in the last line:

```
select fn_must_edukas()
```

It should be:

```
select * FROM fn_must_edukas()
```

Because you are returning a table.

Comment: I should add this to function call line?

Comment: You have to REPLACE your last line with the one in my example.